# Erro não aparece em página de login e programa fecha quando executado no emulador

Tags: java, android-studio, login

Eu estou fazendo uma página de login que se os dados estiverem corretos ou incorretos aparece um toast exibindo o resultado.

O problema é que não aparece o erro (quando existe algum) e quando executado no emulador o aplicativo para de funcionar.

**Código:**

```
package com.example.appteste;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private login mLogin = new login();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        this.mLogin.nome = findViewById(R.id.nome);
        this.mLogin.senha = findViewById(R.id.senha);
        this.mLogin.button.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if ("Arthur" == this.mLogin.nome.getText().toString() & "123" == this.mLogin.senha.getText().toString()) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Usuario e senha correto!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Usuario ou senha incorretos!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
    private static class login {
        EditText nome;
        EditText senha;
        Button button;
    }
}
```

Comment: Você tem que mostrar o stack error, assim terá a causa do erro, tente converter os parâmetros para: this.mLogin.nome = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nome);

Comment: Erro no emulador: http://prntscr.com/o9r9vz 
Erro Console: coloquei no post

Comment: Fiz oque você falou e deu o mesmo problema.

Comment: é só remover o this.mLogin.button.setOnClickListener(this);
Que o aplicativo abre mais nao consigo executar o evento sem essa linha.

Comment: Adicione está linha nó método onCreate this.mLogin.button = (Button) findViewById(R.Id.button);  button deve ser o nome da variável que está nó teu XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu consegui colocando uma TextView no lugar do toast.

**Código:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private login mLogin = new login();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    this.mLogin.nome = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nome);
    this.mLogin.senha = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.senha);
    final TextView resultado = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resultado);
    Button botao = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    botao.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if ("Arthur" == mLogin.nome.getText().toString() & "123" == mLogin.senha.getText().toString()) {
                resultado.setText("Usuario e senha corretos!");

            } else {
                resultado.setText("Usuario ou senha incorretos!");
            }
        }
    });
}


private static class login {
    EditText nome;
    EditText senha;
    Button button;
    EditText resultado;
}
}
```